# CFLOOP and SQL Update

Tags: ms-access, coldfusion, sql-update, cfloop

How do I use CFLOOP for updating my records on Access DB? I have tried using the code below but it seems it gives me a duplicated value instead of an increment

My code:

```
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="3">
<cfquery name="query" datasource="datasource">
    update mytable
    set
    columnB = #i#
    where columnA = 'a'                                          
   </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

Output of records under columnB= all number 3, it should be 1,2,3

My table looks like this....

```
Column A|ColumnA1|ColumnB
A         A        
A         B
A         C
```

Columns A and A1 is filled with a previous CFLOOP and SQL Insert.

Comment: What are the values of columnA?

Comment: A repeated string character, in this situation it is the letter 'A'

Comment: That's why @Busche's answer is correct.

Comment: @DanBracuk not sure what you're saying, the SQL needs to be more specific to update only select rows, includomg ColumnA1 in it as well for example, would make it only update one row instead of all three.

Comment: @Ace09 - *Output of records under columnB= all number 3, it should be 1,2,3*  **Why**? You need more criteria than just `WHERE columnA = 'a'`, because that matches *all* of your sample records. So every time you loop, all of the records are set to the same value.  You have not told us *why* the `ColumnB` values should be set to `1, 2 and 3`. Once you explain that, we can suggest the proper code.

Comment: Also, that kind of looping seems a little suspicious. What is the real goal, and is this a one time or recurring update? Because there may be more efficient options ..

Comment: @Leigh, I am designing a simple multiple choice application for an elearning website. I need to use SQL update since CLOOP could only loop insert one set of data at a time.

Comment: @Ace09 - Well that still does not tell us enough ;-) Are you trying to populate some "master" Q&A table or process user responses? We need to see the 1) [table ddl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language#CREATE_statements) 2) a more complete sample of the data used for the update 3) *and* the "desired" results.  That said  ... based on what little you have described, you may want to rethink your table structure. Q&A type applications usually store the data (ie questionID & related answerID) in rows, not columns, because it provides much greater flexibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're updating all the records that have columnA = 'a' each time you run the update, you need more criteria in your where clause to stop updating multiples rows at once.

You can easily see how many rows were updated by using the result attribute of cfquery, similar to the code below.

```
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="3">
<cfquery name="query" datasource="datasource" result='updated'>
    update mytable
    set
    columnB = #i#
    where columnA = 'a'                                          
   </cfquery>
   <cfdump var='#updated#' />
</cfloop>
```

**Update:**
Given your updated question, an example updated query may look like so, as the combination of columnA and ColumnA1 make the row unique.

```
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="3">
<cfquery name="query" datasource="datasource" result='updated'>
    update mytable
    set
    columnB = #i#
    where columnA = 'a'      
    AND ColumnA1 = <cfqueryparam value='#i#' />                                    
   </cfquery>
   <cfdump var='#updated#' />
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the query is updating all of the records where `columnA` is equal to `a` (as opposed to all records in the table).

Comment: @Busches, I have tried your updated code, it seems to give me an array and it does not update ColumnB. Is the value of ColumnB be the same for ColumnA1 from the cfquery? They both use the variable i... Thank you for the quick reply

Comment: The updated variable will give you a struct of variables. The code I gave you is pseudo code, it won't necessarily work for your exact need without some tweaking. I used the variable I again as that's the only variable you have in the loop, again, you'll need to tweak the code to get it to work, but it should set you in the right direction.

Comment: The record didn't update, because the value of columnA1 is never 1, 2, or 3 which is the what this latest answer is saying to do.  Just change "where columnA = 'a'"  to "where columnA1 = 'a'" and Bob will be your uncle.